# Retrieve a value from an XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PutUserLinkRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <request xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <id S="ID-KMEHR" SV="1.0" SL="">Delta.PutUserLink.25/08/2017 13:07:43</id>
    <author>
      <hcparty>
      </hcparty>
    </author>
  </request>
  <userlink xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <user1>
      <cd S="CD-USERTYPE" SV="1.0" SL="" DN="" L="fr">patient</cd>
      <patient>
        <id S="ID-PATIENT" SV="1.0" SL="">97031038713</id>
      </patient>
    </user1>
    <user2>
    </user2>
    <type S="CD-USERLINK" SV="1.0" SL="" DN="" L="fr">patientassent</type>

  </userlink>
</PutUserLinkRequest>
```

I cannot retrieve the value `97031038713`

```
XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

_xmlDoc.LoadXml(_mRec.Content);

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(_xmlDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns","http://tempuri.org");
```

Then I tried different things but without success

---

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PutUserLinkRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <request xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <id S="ID-KMEHR" SV="1.0" SL="">Delta.PutUserLink.25/08/2017 13:07:43</id>
    <author>
      <hcparty>
      </hcparty>
    </author>
  </request>
  <userlink xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <user1>
      <cd S="CD-USERTYPE" SV="1.0" SL="" DN="" L="fr">patient</cd>
      <patient>
        <id S="ID-PATIENT" SV="1.0" SL="">97031038713</id>
      </patient>
    </user1>
    <user2>
    </user2>
    <type S="CD-USERLINK" SV="1.0" SL="" DN="" L="fr">patientassent</type>

  </userlink>
</PutUserLinkRequest>
```

Comment: You should edit your question; the xml is broken ;)

Comment: Formatted Code, removed fluff for readability

Comment: "Then I tried different things but without success"  Maybe if you showed us what you tried, we can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this trivially with LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org";

var id = (string) doc.Descendants(ns + "patient")
    .Elements(ns + "id")
    .Single();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mKpw8I) for a demo.